# Problem with decoding JSON data from Pusher API in flutter

Tags: flutter, api, crash, decode, pusher

I am using Pusher API as real time database.
I can successfully connected and getting data in JSON format.
Problem: I couldn't decode it. I am using jsonDecode(); but that's not working as follow. [Here is the screenshot of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICz2X.png).

Anyone have solution? Any other way to decode it?

```
Future<void> _initPusher() async{
  PusherClient pusher;
  Channel channel;
  pusher = new PusherClient(
    "adb844af65547f4a67cf",
    PusherOptions(
      cluster: "mt1",
    ),
    enableLogging: true,
  );

  channel = pusher.subscribe("my-channel-chat");

  pusher.onConnectionError((error) {
    print("error: ${error!.message}");
  });

  channel.bind('my-event-chat', (event) {
    // print(event!.data.toString());
    final data = jsonDecode(event!.data.toString());
    print (data);
  });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to put a comma at the end of the line to make it valid JSON. Currently it is:

```
{
"sender":"you"
"message":"Something to say"
"time":"00.00"
}
```

Try with

```
{
"sender":"you",
"message":"Something to say",
"time":"00.00"
}
```

You can use services such as https://jsonlint.com/ to check whether your JSON is valid.